# Scrolling and touch events on iOS5

Tags: javascript, css, ios5, touch, mobile-safari

I have a list of tweets that you can scroll with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch`. Each time you tap on tweet, it logs its number in a section at the top of the screen. So far, so good.

The problem is: when I launch a scroll and I try then to stop the ongoing scroll, I don't want to consider that tap as a "real" tap. That tap should just stop the current scroll but it shouldn't log any info.

You can try it by yourself on the iPhone or the simulator with this [simple example](http://sharedfil.es/test-pB2yDNRqYo.html). Here's a [quick screencast](http://sharedfil.es/Screen%20Recording-A4Epx5Ag7q.mov) showing the bug.

I hope I'm being clear enough!

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a variable in touchStart, then check for it in touchEnd and also check the change in x/y positions. If they haven't moved (more than say, 5px), it is a "tap" and not a "scroll".